# Importing SpiDev Library In Eclipse - PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-import

I've successfully installed **PyDev Plugin** to my **Eclipse IDE**.
I'm trying to import **SpiDev** Library but it cannot be found.

What I tried so far:

- I added **SpiDev** as an External Library, one time from Github from [here](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev), and another time from PyPI but no luck yet.

The Interpreter already set to `Python`.

[A Closer Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IJsT.png)

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Due to the fact that I don't have enough rep. The above question is currently the best that I can provide (limitation on links and images ..etc). Any edit is very welcome.

Comment: You should paste the error message text into your question instead of an image link.  This make the question more searchable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is just using pypi (unless you're going to develop itself).

So, the steps would be:

`pip install spidev`

(the version you just got from github in your screenshot will not work because it's a compiled module -- i.e.: it needs to generate a spydev.so -- and you didn't compile it... if you `pip install` it, it should do that by default).

So, after installing it with pip, it should work, provided you installed it in the proper interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's already installed on my device, though it's not working. *provided you installed it in the proper interpreter* ..would ya please show me how to do it ?

Comment: The only thing here is that the `pip` you use must be the same for the interpreter you have installed. If you open a Python shell -- out of Eclipse and do: `python -c "from spidev import SpiDev;print(SpiDev)"` does it work?

Comment: Sorry, I'm now at home, I will try that once back at work on Monday.
I've installed SpiDev before I installed PyDev Plugin. So I'm not sure what does that mean: *you use must be the same for the interpreter you have installed*. However, please excuse my ignorance here because I'm very newbie in Python and I'm trying my best. 
I'll accept your answer for now. And I hope ya help me to pass this obstacle. Thanks again.

Comment: Someone mentioned in another answer about `pip` command that: *Using PIP, You can install the module. It will install the dependency also.*. I think I installed SpiDev on my device without using `pip`, so do ya think that's the reason. What is the difference if I installed it with/without using `pip`?

Comment: Well, that library has a compiled module (i.e.: it's not pure Python), so, if you installed without pip, you still have to make sure to compile it (otherwise it won't work) -- if you didn't compile it, that could be the reason (pip will do that for you by default).